# How to call page like fragment with android studio default sample

Tags: android, android-fragments

I create a new sample app using android studio and I get a sample with `extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`.

How I can call a page **(like using fragment)** when Menu Item on Drawer Menu clicked?

This is my code

```
package com.bertho.testapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

import model.Movie;
import model.MoviesResponse;
import rest.ApiClient;
import rest.ApiInterface;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private final static String API_KEY = "1112223333";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            showToast("Menu Import");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            showToast("Menu Galery");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            showToast("Menu Slide Show");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
            showToast("Menu Tools");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            showToast("Menu Share");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
            showToast("Menu Send");
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }



    public void sampleConnect() {

        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<MoviesResponse> call = apiService.getTopRatedMovies(API_KEY);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<MoviesResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MoviesResponse> call, Response<MoviesResponse> response) {
                int statusCode = response.code();
                List<Movie> movies = response.body().getResults();
                Log.d(TAG, "NUMBER OF MOVIES RECEIVED : " + movies.size());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MoviesResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                // Log error here since request failed
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
    }


    public void showToast(String output){
        Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), output, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

How do I get I can call a new page for each menu on the menu I clicked (**onNavigationItemSelected**) like using a fragment? Or should I replace

`extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`

with

`extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener`

for my case?

Please help

Comment: do you have framelayout indside activity_main?

Comment: @Sreekanth my activity_main : http://pastebin.com/Fx7S6h2E

Comment: You should have framelayout there you add views using fragment

Comment: I see....like my sample code before. FrameLayout in activity_main. But how I can use Fragment code combine with default sample from android studio? Click event when menu Item clicked @Sreekanth

Comment: check my code below and item clicks add switch case logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet

add this to xml inside drawer layout

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Java

create object of fragment

```
Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment();

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
```

Comment: you got solutions?

Comment: Hai @Sreekanth Sorry for the late reply. I was back online. Ok, I will try to incorporate into my layout FrameLayout. If I find obstacles will I contact you again

Comment: Good go ahead...if any other question post question url here..get back you...thanks

Comment: Hai @Sreekanth maybe you can help with my another issue here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969080/always-error-android-support-v7-widget-recyclerview-setlayoutmanager

Comment: @BerthoJoris You got solution?

Comment: Yes, but unfinished @Sreekanth

Comment: Try like -- mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager((Activity)this));