# 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.canScrollVertically()'

Tags: java, android, xml

How to fix my issue when I try to use **RecyclerView**. When I add 2 line of code

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.movies_recycler_view);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

My code always show **error**

```
06-22 19:52:25.801 19743-19743/com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp, PID: 19743
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp/com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
at com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

How to fix my issue? It looks like `RecyclerView.setLayoutManager` but I cant resolve my issue alone.

This is my code (**ChannelAdapter.java**)

```
package adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp.R;

import java.util.List;

import model.Channel;


public class ChannelAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChannelAdapter.ChannelViewHolder> {

    private List<Channel> channels;
    private int rowLayout;
    private Context context;

    public static class ChannelViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        LinearLayout moviesLayout;
        TextView movieTitle;
        TextView data;
        TextView movieDescription;
        TextView rating;

        TextView name;
        TextView code;
        TextView description;
        TextView number;
        TextView definition;
        TextView paket;
        ImageView logo;

        public ChannelViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            moviesLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.movies_layout);
            name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            definition = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
            description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);
//            rating = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        }
    }

    public ChannelAdapter(List<Channel> channels, int rowLayout, Context context) {
        this.channels = channels;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ChannelAdapter.ChannelViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                            int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
        return new ChannelViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ChannelViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.name.setText(channels.get(position).getName());
        holder.definition.setText(channels.get(position).getDefinition());
        holder.description.setText(channels.get(position).getDescription());
//        holder.rating.setText(channels.get(position).getVoteAverage().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return channels.size();
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/movies_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and My **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

import adapter.ChannelAdapter;
import model.Channel;
import model.ChannelResponse;
import model.Movie;
import model.MoviesResponse;
import page.DefaultFragment;
import page.HomeFragment;
import page.ProfileFragment;
import rest.ApiClient;
import rest.ApiInterface;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private final static String API_KEY = "7e8f60e325cd06e164799af1e317d7a7";

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.movies_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        Fragment fragment = null;
        fragment = new DefaultFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.root, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = "Home";
            getChannelData();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            fragment = new ProfileFragment();
            title = "Profile";
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.root, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            // set the toolbar title
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public void getChannelData() {
        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getChannel().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<ChannelResponse> call = apiService.getItems();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ChannelResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ChannelResponse> call, Response<ChannelResponse> response) {
                int statusCode = response.code();
                List<Channel> channel = response.body().getItems();
                Log.d(TAG, "NUMBER OF MOVIES RECEIVED : " + channel.size());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new ChannelAdapter(channel, R.layout.list_channel, getApplicationContext()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ChannelResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                // Log error here since request failed
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
    }


    public void showToast(String output){
        Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), output, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Maybe I forgot to change something, please help...

Thanks

Comment: Looks like your `recyclerView` is null

Comment: Yes @ArbenMaloku maybe you can show me how to fix my code

Comment: Your `activity_main.xml` does not have the RecyclerView. Move it there or do your login in the Fragment

Comment: Can you show us the Fragment where are you inflating this layout `fragment_home.xml`? As I can see you need to call `findViewById(...)` in a class which extends `Fragment`?

Comment: you are having your recycler view in `fragment_home.xml` and your trying to inflate it from `activity_main.xml`.. so you're getting NPE.

Answer (score 1):

Your `recyclerView` is null.
Because the RecyclerView is only added when `fragment_home.xml` is loaded to your activity.

That mean it is ready after (assuming your DefaultFragment is inflate `fragment_home.xml`)

```
Fragment fragment = null;
fragment = new DefaultFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.root, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

You should do the findViewById after that.
**However, `fragmentTransaction.commit();` is an async process. The fragment content may not be available immediately after that.**
So, you will need to call [`fragmentTransaction.commitNow()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commitNow()) to make sure the fragment is added to activity.

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.movies_recycler_view);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

It is not a very good idea to find fragment's view from the activity level. One of the reason is to avoid the situation like you are facing now as fragment content cannot be guaranteed in activity.

The better way is to find and set view content inside the fragment `onViewCreated`

If your data is get from activity, you can still pass the data to fragment from activity.

See, topics like "communication between fragment and activity"
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Hi @OnJohn I try your solution findViewById afterDefaultFragment called, but always the same error

Comment: I guess that could happen too. As `fragmentTransaction.commit();` is a async process, that means the fragment may not be available immediately.
I think you should try to find the view in fragment level.
Let me update the answer too

Comment: A simpler way is to call `fragmentTransaction.commitNow()` to ensure the fragment is added. Check my update :)

Comment: Hi  @OnJohn .commitNow() is no available. See : https://s32.postimg.org/8jatjnb9h/error.png

Comment: The method is available in support lib 24.0+. Please update your gradle to use the least support lib 24.0.0

Comment: Hai @OnJohn commitNow() has done but still have the same issue. Two screen stacked

Comment: From your code, I couldn't find the reason that can produce screen stack.
You may have to check all your `FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction` to see which cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.movies_recycler_view);
// The above line doesnot throw null pointer exception, since you can cast null to any object. Refer this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723596/no-exception-while-type-casting-with-a-null-in-java
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
// The above line will throw null pointer exception, since here we are accessing the null object and invoking a method on that null object.
```

Try like this to avoid the null pointer exception

```
 recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.movies_recycler_view);
 if(recyclerView != null) {     
     recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
     .....
     .....
     .....
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either move `fragment_home.xml` code inside your `main.xml` file, If you want `recyclerView` inside your `activity`. i.e.

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/movies_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**OR**

add a `Fragment` to your `activity` which inflates `fragment_home.xml` and move `recyclerView` initialization code to your `fragment`. i.e. Below code in your fragment:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.movies_recycler_view);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Comment: Hi @himanshu1496 I try your first solution and works. But when I click on other menu (like second menu) the view become stacked. see : https://s32.postimg.org/qmro4tpwl/error.png

Comment: Yes it will because you must be loading on the same `frameLayout`, now  if you want to go ahead with the first solution then set some background color say white, for view which is on top and make the parent layout clickable so that user will not notice that view is stacked.

Comment: second solution would be to load a new fragment and put recyclerView there and every time you want another fragment to load, just replace the first fragment.

Comment: Okay since you are following the solution first, I'll give the solution for that,  the layout used in the fragment loaded by second menu click, add `android:background="#FFFFFF"` and `android:clickable="true"` in xml for parent layout. Please let me know if you have any trouble implementing